# My cpu fan makes more noise while running Ubuntu 13.04?

Tags: ati

I have

- AMD Athlon x3 processor
- gigabyte GA-MA74GMT-S2 motherboard
- 6gb ddr3 ram
- ati 4350 hd 1gb graphics card.

Comment: "more" implies you have a situation with that you compare. So what is your reference?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [loud fan on Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/464745/loud-fan-on-ubuntu-14-04)

Answer (score -1):

Try cleaning fan for dust ! :)

Comment: Please don't add comments as answers. Invest some time in the site and you will gain sufficient [privileges](http://askubuntu.com/help/privileges) to upvote answers you like, or to add actual comments when seeking clarification of any issues.

Comment: edwin that takes 50 points of reputation for the feature to be enabled. thanks for doing -1 post, earlier i was at 43, but people here ensure that i should never reach that 50 target. coz of -1 it made my score to 41. thanks (now do tell me how can i comment in that very particular section) ? thanks

Comment: Just invest some time in the site! Try learning from experience, this is how the site works: you should add fulsome answers.